# Vertx: resource allocation when verticles are idle?

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x

I am pretty new to Vertx and have been experimenting with Vertx 3 in my app. So far it seem really useful in some scenarios. But I do have a question that I would like a comprehensive answer on, since the documentation and Google do not provide any information on this.

It seems (through my observation) that in a simple application not using clustered vertx, each verticle deployed is maintained by a separate thread. But currently my app (i.e. a web application using some other framework) is not using vertx all the way, (meaning that a lot of business logic does not involve vertx andthe verticles deployed are not always busy and only perform operations in a relatively infrequent manner). I wonder in this scenario, would the threads be freed up by vertx when the verticles are deployed but idle, and only utilized when they receive events? Or will they occupy the threads and not allow the non-vertx parts of the application utilize them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this part is covered quite well: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor

> Vert.x works differently here. Instead of a single event loop, each
>   Vertx instance maintains several event loops. By default we choose the
>   number based on the number of available cores on the machine, but this
>   can be overridden.

Where you're wrong is that verticle bound to a thread is a verticle occupying a thread. Let's say you have 4 CPUs and 1 verticle. VertX will allocate 4 threads to it's EventLoop. You start 100 vertices? VertX will still use 4 threads.

But, if Verticle34, let's say, starts on Thread2, then gets suspended, it will always resume on the same thread.

---

Let's see some code now:

```
public class EventLoopExample {

static Map<String, AtomicInteger> threadCounts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printActive("Before starting VertX");

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    printActive("After starting VertX");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle());
        printActive("Regular verticle deployed");
    }

    printActive("Before deploying worker verticles");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle(), new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true));
        printActive("Worker verticle deployed");
    }

    printActive("After everything deployed");

    System.out.println(new TreeMap(threadCounts));

    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    threadCounts.forEach((key, value) -> {
        count.addAndGet(value.get());
    });

    System.out.println(count.get());
}

private static void printActive(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
    System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
}

static class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        threadCounts.putIfAbsent(Thread.currentThread().getName(), new AtomicInteger(0));
        threadCounts.get(Thread.currentThread().getName()).incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Stopped");
    }
}
}
```

Note:
Before VertX starts you have 2 threads active
Startup of VertX adds 2 more threads, even if you don't have verticles deployed
Number of EventLoop threads is defined by number of cores. Since I have 8 cores, VertX creates maximum of 8 threads.
Worker pool is 20 threads by default.
So, unless you create more WorkerPools or play with configuration any other way, VertX won't use more than ~32 threads.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I would still like to know, in the case where a bunch of verticles remaining idle, would it be a performance impacting overhead?

Comment: Short answer is "No, it won't affect your performance". I updated my original answer with explanation and examples.